# How can I get a third column with the count of rows, after a groupby function in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, count

I'm learning pandas and have a query about aggregate functions. Apologies for what might be a very basic question for experts on this forum :).

Here's a sample of my dataset:

```
     EmpID   Age_Range   Salary

0   321          20, 35   34000


1   561         20, 35    24000


2   789         50, 65     34000
```

the above dataset is df, and i'm saving down avg. salary info per employee age range into a separate dataframe (df_age), where I'm persisting the above data. I was able to successfully apply mean() on the salary table to get the avg. salary per age range.

So basically what I want is the count of employees for each age_range.
`df_age['EmpCount'] = df.groupby('Age_Range')['EmpID'].count()` doesn't work, and returns a 'NaN' in my dataset.

additionally, when I used the transform function

```
df_age['EmpCount'] = df.groupby('Age_Range')['EmpID'].transform(count)
```

it returns values, but the same value across the three age ranges - 37, which is not correct. There are a total of 100 entries in my dataset.

desired output for df_age:

```
0 (20, 35]  50000  27
1 (35, 50]  37000  11 
2 (50, 65]  65000  30
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain the logic of the desired output? Anyhow, consider using `size` aggregation function

Comment: Sure - thanks. the first column is the index, the second is the age range, the third is the average salary per age range, and the fourth column is the number of employees per age range.

Comment: could you show an example and the expected output? (which can be obtained from the example)

Comment: Hi ansev - the expected output with examples \is the last table in my query above. The explanation for each column is in my comment above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you want a new column which has count of employees for age_range. Well, you can use aggregate function to get your answer as follows:

```
df_age = df.set_index(['Age_Range','EmpID']).groupby(level =0).size().reset_index(name='count_of_employees') 
df_age['Ave_Salary'] = df.set_index(['Age_Range','Salary']).groupby(level =0).mean()
```

Comment: Thank you. I've edited my query above as there was an error in my initial post. As you will Your second line of code is what I used the first time round, but this only returned 'NaN'.

Whilst the first line of your code worked perfectly - this has the effect of removing the average salary figure which I was able to retrieve the first time round. When I attempted to run that code by replacing df_age with df_age['EmpCount'], I again got 'NaN'.

Finally, I think np.count is wrong as I had to use np.size - but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: Oh, I believe using the first code it made a newdataframe, which doesn't have the columns of the previous one. If you want to make change to your current dataframe you can do that by using multi-index: Like `df = df.set_index(['Age_Range','EmpID'], inplace = True) 
df = df.groupby(level =0).size().reset_index(name='count_of_employees')`

These should provide you with all you need with index as the count, or whatever you want it to be, you can reset.

Comment: Hi - still no luck am afraid - this returns the employee count correctly, but doesn't give me avg salary per age range.

Comment: Ohh, I think you also want a column for average salary and a column for count of employees, than this should suffice: basically the first method used two times one for count and then for average salary:
`df_age = df.set_index(['Age_Range','EmpID'], inplace = True) df = df.groupby(level =0).size().reset_index(name='count_of_employees')
df_age = df.set_index(['Age_Range','Salary'], inplace = True) df = df.groupby(level =0).size().reset_index(name='Ave_salary')`
This should give you both count and average salary. Than you can reset you index as per your wish!

Comment: Should it be df, or df_age in your second line of code please?

Comment: df itself as I believe Salary column is originally in df dataframe; otherwise you can also use the below code which has better readability I believe, but a bit longer:
`df.groupby('Age_Range',inplace = True)
df_age = df.filter(['Age_Range'], axis =1)
df_age['Ave_Salary'] = df[['Salary']].mean(axis = 1)
df_age['Count of employees'] = df[['EmpID']].size( axis =1)`

Comment: Ohh, I believe the previous code should be without inplace that was a mistake from my side Here I have corrected it, you can use any of this or the one I just provided in the previous comment:
`df_age = df.set_index(['Age_range','EmpID']).groupby(level =0).size().reset_index(name = 'count_of_emp')
df_age['Ave_Salary'] = df.set_index(['Age_Range','Salary']).groupby(level=0).mean()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `size` or `len` in a transform, just like you did with `count`:

```
# Dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({"sample": ["sample1", "sample2", "sample2", "sample3", "sample3", "sample3"]})

df["number_of_samples"] = df.groupby("sample").sample.transform("size")
df["number_of_samples_again"] = df.groupby("sample").sample.transform(len)
```

Output:

```
    sample  number_of_samples  number_of_samples_again
0  sample1                  1                        1
1  sample2                  2                        2
2  sample2                  2                        2
3  sample3                  3                        3
4  sample3                  3                        3
5  sample3                  3                        3
```

Comment: Thank you- unfortunately this didn't work. I tried:
df_age['EmpCount'] = df.reset_index().groupby('Age_Range', as_index=True)['EmpID'].agg(np.size)

Comment: Sorry, am I missing something here, or are you telling me you tried something else than what I suggested, and what you tried did not work?

Comment: Hi - I took your advice to use size or len, but not in the manner you suggested as I don't understand how it fits my situation. I also tried using the code in my comment, which didn't work.

Comment: Ok, what I'm saying is you can do literally what you wrote (`df_age['EmpCount'] = df.groupby('Age_Range')['EmpID'].transform(count)`) except use `len` or `"size"` instead of `count`. That doesn't work? As in: `df_age['EmpCount'] = df.groupby('Age_Range')['EmpID'].transform(len)` or `df_age['EmpCount'] = df.groupby('Age_Range')['EmpID'].transform("size")`.

Comment: Understood - thank you. Unfortunately, these don't work. I've been reading up about similar issues on stack overflow, and believe this has to do with indexing? Not sure.

Comment: It works for me when I'm using your example data. What's going wrong?

Comment: Not sure... when you say it works, are you getting a table similar to my output above?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this, but it's not neat / efficient:

```
df_age1 = df.groupby('Age_Range')['Salary'].mean()
df_age1 = df_age1.reset_index()
df_age1.rename(columns={'Salary':'SalAvg'}, inplace=True)

df_age2 = df.groupby('Age_Range')['EmpID'].count()
df_age2 = df_age2.reset_index()
df_age2.rename(columns={'EmpID':'EmpCount'}, inplace=True)
```

Then finally,

```
df_age = pd.merge(df_age1, df_age2, on='Age_Range')
```

The above iteration gives me what I need, but across three dataframes - I'll obviously be ignoring df_age1 and 2, but I'm still on the lookout for an efficient answer!